# Let $\mu$ be a Borel probability measure on $X$ and $A$ its support. Which conditions on $X$ that makes $[A \neq \emptyset \implies \mu(A)=1]$ hold?

Tags: general-topology, probability-theory, measure-theory, metric-spaces, borel-measures

Let $X$ be a topological space and $\mu$ a Borel probability measure on $X$. Let $A := \operatorname{supp} \mu$ be the intersection of all closed sets with full measure. Then $A$ is closed and thus measurable. If $X$ is a separable or a locally compact metric space, [then](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44408/measure-of-the-support-of-a-borel-probability-on-a-metric-space) $\mu (A) = 1$.

> Now we only assume $A \neq \emptyset$. Could we prove that $\mu(A)=1$? If not, which conditions on $X$ that makes $\mu(A)=1$ hold?

Comment: So, you assume that there exists closed $A(\ne\emptyset)$ s.t. $\mu(A^c)=0$?

Comment: @d.k.o. yess. To be specific, I assume $\operatorname{supp} \mu \neq \emptyset$.